# Stripping date/time delimiters in an SSIS csv export

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I am exporting a csv from a table query via SSIS export. I would like to be able to strip the spaces, colons, fractions of the seconds, and dashes out of the datetime field when the export to csv takes place.  Is this possible in SQL and SSIS data export packages?

Current Actual Result

```
747,2019-08-15 3:26:00.673000000,55596,3,4190002543,Q,1,3.9900000000000002,1,0
```

Desired Result

```
747,20190815132600,55596,3,4190002543,Q,1,3.9900000000000002,1,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I will assume that you are using SQL Server Import and Export wizard*

Instead of selecting a Table as a source ,[you can use an SQL command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/provide-a-source-query-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) and remove these characters: *assuming that `Col2` is the date column*

```sql
select 
Col1,
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Col2],1,charindex('.',[Col2],1) - 1),'-',''),':',''),' ',''),
Col3,
...
FROM Table
```

If the column date type is datetime then you can use `FORMAT()` function

```sql
SELECT
Col1,
FORMAT(Col2,'yyyyMMddHHmmss')
Col3,
...
FROM Table
```

Comment: The only issue I have had with this is I have the data, but the date/time column header has been removed while all the others have been left.  Pretty weird.

Comment: @AnthonyBondi Try adding an alias as `FORMAT(Col2,'yyyyMMddHHmmss') as Col2`

Comment: AWESOME! I knew I was forgetting a simple piece after the format.  Thanks a ton.